# Saving MS word (docx) as pdf on Mac OS X with one click using macros

Tags: vba, macos, pdf, ms-word, macos-sierra

I have a question on how to edit the following macros to save MS word (.docx) file as PDF on macOS Sierra without .docx in the file name. That is, the macros works perfectly BUT it always saves files as, for example, letter.docx.pdf. It is a very easy option to save in pdf with one click only.

And I would appreciate if someone could help to me amend the macros below so that there is no .docx in the file name. I have tried to hide extensions in Finder, but that does not seem to help:

---

```
Sub SaveActiveDocAsPDF()

On Error Resume Next

ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
fileName:=ActiveDocument.FullName & ".pdf", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
End Sub
```

---

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the existing file extension before adding the new one. Like this:

```
Sub SaveActiveDocAsPDF()

On Error Resume Next

Dim saveName As String
saveName = ActiveDocument.FullName
saveName = Left(saveName, Len(saveName) - 5) & ".pdf"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=saveName, _
FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for me in Feb 2018. After 1) adding the macro, 2) saving the doc as a macro enabled doc, and 3) adding this macro to the quick access toolbar. That gives pdfs with one-button click.